# Multimeter range

Tags: power-supply, resistors, resistance, multimeter, electromagnetic

I've been using a small multimeter meter and the problem is that anytime I want to measure amperage that exceeds 200 mA, I have to switch the red probe the 10 A port. Unfortunately, I can't get the precise reading: instead of getting something like 0.025 (considering the scale or range is a larger), I get 0.012 mA. I was want to clear the confusion: is there any additional arithmetic needed to get the actual value?

Comment: Your multimeter doesn't likely read "0.012mA" on the 10A scale - did you mean **0.012A**? With no probe(s), does it read zero? If you switch probes so current goes the other way, does it read **-0.012**? These simple meters might have two internal fuses: one for the more sensitive scales, and one 10A fuse dedicated for 10A scale - are they still good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the high-current terminal, multimeters typically switch to Ampere scale, so you'd read the current in Amperes.

Regarding accuracy, both the internal resistance of the meter and its accuracy are different through the two paths.

On the 10A scale, the typical accuracy of 1.5%+3digits would mean that a 25.0mA current is displayed as anything from 0.021 to 0.029.

On the 200mA scale, the same current, at the same accuracy would read 24.62 to 25.37

Keeping in mind that when placed in circuit, the meter changes the resistance of the measured path, and that the meter's 10A circuit is different than its common circuit, it's possible that the actual current is different between the two measurements.

To interpret the reading correctly, you should apply the math suggested by the meter's accuracy specification and calibration. If your reading is 0.012 on the 10A scale, the actual current could be up to +/- 1.5% and 3 digits away from that reading, assuming the same typical accuracy I used above, ie, 8mA to 15mA

If you need more accurate and repeatable measurements, you can measure the voltage drop across a known path, and divide by its known resistance. Your measurement is still off due to accuracy spec, but the measurement won't be affecting the circuit, and you'll need to either do a bit of math, or use an in-circuit precision shunt resistor, which is designed specifically to allow accurate current sensing and measurement.